# Python new FontManager

Tags: matplotlib, fonts

Hi everybody I have developed more than one years ago a qulityplot (for publications) library ..

now there is this 3 line in my base class:

```
font_dirs = ['/home/marco/.fonts', ]
font_files = font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=font_dirs)
font_list = font_manager.createFontList(font_files)
font_manager.fontManager.ttflist.extend(font_list)
```

but when I run any class for plot defined in this library (inherited from the base class whit the 4 lines above) I got this message:

```
The createFontList function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.2 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use FontManager.addfont instead.
/usr/lib/python3.7/_collections_abc.py:841: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Support for setting the 'text.latex.preamble' or 'pgf.preamble' rcParam to a list of strings is deprecated since 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later; set it to a single string instead.
  self[key] = other[key]
```

Can somebody help me understand what I have to modify in order to make everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the preamble for the pgf and LATEX settings of my plots:

I had to change the following code:

```
pgf_with_latex = {                      # setup matplotlib to use latex for output
"pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",        # change this if using xetex or lautex
"text.usetex": True,                # use LaTeX to write all text
"font.family": "serif",
"font.serif": [],                   # blank entries should cause plots
"font.sans-serif": [],              # to inherit fonts from the document
"font.monospace": [],
"axes.labelsize": 10,               # LaTeX default is 10pt font.
"font.size": 10,
"legend.fontsize": 8,               # Make the legend/label fonts
"xtick.labelsize": 8,               # a little smaller
"ytick.labelsize": 8,
"figure.figsize": figsize(0.9),     # default fig size of 0.9 textwidth
"pgf.preamble": [
    r"\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}",    # use utf8 fonts
    r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",        # plots will be generated
    r"\usepackage[detect-all,locale=DE]{siunitx}",
    ]                                   # using this preamble
}
```

to:

```
pgf_with_latex = {                   # setup matplotlib to use latex for output      # change this if using xetex or lautex
"pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
"text.usetex": True,           # use LaTeX to write all text
"font.family": "serif",
"font.serif": [],                   # blank entries should cause plots
"font.sans-serif": [],              # to inherit fonts from the document
"font.monospace": [],
"axes.labelsize": 10,               # LaTeX default is 10pt font.
"font.size": 10,
"legend.fontsize": 8,               # Make the legend/label fonts
"xtick.labelsize": 8,               # a little smaller
"ytick.labelsize": 8,
"pgf.preamble": r"\usepackage[detect-all,locale=DE]{siunitx} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}"}
```

You just have to rewrite your lists (here in pgf.preamble) to a single string.